# Angular 8 routing changes unintentionally querystring order

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular8

Building an app using Angular 8 as landing page that accepts dynamic query strings within the redirect link which contains some query string keys as number like: `42=17` so for example when I hit in the browser the full link as follow with:

`http://localhost:4200/success?id1=123&42=17&hash=qwertzuiop`

**Result**: It changed the sequence unintentionally to:

`http://localhost:4200/success?42=17&id1=123&hash=qwertzuiop`

**Expected**: To maintain the same order of the query string as I need to check the hash string against the original url if it's altered and of course when the sequence changes, the hash function result changes consequently.

---

**Code sample**:

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SuccessComponent } from './success/success.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'success', component: SuccessComponent },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

success.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-success',
  templateUrl: './success.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./success.component.scss']
})

export class SuccessComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.queryParams);
    // {42: "17", id1: "123", hash: "qwertzuiop"}

    console.log(this.router.routerState.snapshot.url);
    // /success?42=17&id1=123&hash=qwertzuiop
  }
}
```

Any clue if I can intercept the original URL before matching angular routes and navigating?

Comment: I have no idea about this, but to solve your issue when creating hash, sort keys alphabetically and when you want to regenerate hash, sort keys same order as well, then hash will be same

Comment: @RezaRahmati I ain't the one who create the hash just verify it but thanks for the reply

Comment: @BasimHennawi, In javascript, you can't sort the objects. the objects internally sorted to ascending order, we can't change it. that's why the 42 is way ahead of others.

Comment: @BearNithi that's why I ask how to intercept the original url before Angular routing takes place but thanks

Comment: Did you try to console router events - this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
   const page = this.router.url; 
  const location = window.location.href;
});

Comment: @NagaSaiA Yep, but unfortunately also the url was already changed